# Problem with identifying Datetime-index hour for the whole Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time, timestamp

I have a rather strange problem with using dthe `.hour` - Method in my Dataframe.

When I try for a subsample of my dataframe (df) to identify the hours

```
ts = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:10].index)
ts.hour
```

I get the output :

```
Int64Index([11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13], dtype='int64', name='Datum')
```

because the snipit containts the hours from 11 to 13.

But when I try for the whole dataset:

```
ts2 = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
ts2.hour
```

I get:

```
'Index' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

I also tried:

```
ts3 = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:].index)
ts3.hour
```

Which leads to the same error as above.
I am really confused why this is not working. Somehow it seemed to work for a function I had built but now I get this error.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample dataframe that allows us to reproduce the problem, and show your expected output?

Comment: It seems there is an issue in the the column `Datum` in your dataset. Probably when you created the dataset, the `Datum` column dtype might be `object`. You could first convert the type of this column to `datetime64` by doing `df["Datum"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Datum"])`. This line might throw an error if there is invalid input in the column.

Comment: Does your `Datum` column contain other type of data than integers?